# Visual Studio WPF MediaElement not Displaying the video

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

This is my first time asking a question here. So I was following a tutorial (https://youtu.be/-zM486rVopk) then at the MediaElement part I am having a difficulty understanding on what's the source of my problem.

```
        <MediaElement Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6"
                      Source="C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio Workspace\WPFDemo\Resources\Crying Meme.mp4" />
```

Screenshots:
[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReUDg.png)
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbrvr.png)

So I tried dragging the video file towards the form but this error message popped up...

Error: [Error Pop up message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEDLB.png)

I don't know what it means, I'm pretty new to these things and I hope you understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you actually did when "dragging the video file towards the form"?

Comment: Does that happen on one PC but not on others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like it's a path problem, try this:

```
<MediaElement Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" Source="/Resources/Crying Meme.mp4" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried implementing this instead `Source="./Resources/Crying Meme.mp4"`

Comment: Interesting!, I was not able to repro the OP's issue by Copy&Pasting the OP's `MediaElement` xaml code exactly with a slightly different full-path-file-name string. IOW, I'm surprised the OP accepted. My intention is not to hijack this thread so I won't post my xaml here, except when it would help either the OP or the StackOverflow community.

Comment: You may be wondering why I accepted your answer was due to the fact I was able to identify the problem which was regarding the source path. So your answer was helpful.